# Multiple lists and buttons but text input not saving in correct list

Tags: javascript, list, button

I'm trying to create multiple lists on the same page with multiple "Add" buttons.

Entering text in text field 1 and clicking button1 should only add things into list1 (Monday). But button1 is adding text from text field 2 into the last loaded JS which is list2 (Tuesday). There are 8 lists in total I'm only trying to get the first 2 lists working atm.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sarwech/vrn5s2ns/4/

This looks like there isn't proper closure and I've considered creating separate, local functions but I'm not too sure...

The below worked when I only wanted to add items into each list:

document.getElementById("add1").onclick  = function() {

```
var node = document.createElement("Li");
var text = document.getElementById("user_input1").value; 
var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("list_item1").appendChild(node);
localStorage.setItem('monday', JSON.stringify(list_item1));
show();

return false; }
```

document.getElementById("add2").onclick  = function() {

```
var node = document.createElement("Li");
var text = document.getElementById("user_input2").value; 
var textnode=document.createTextNode(text);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("list_item2").appendChild(node); }
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have two `add` function definitions. Because of [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) the latter definition will suppress the former one. That's why you are actually binding tuesday click handler to both tuesday's and monday's add buttons.

You should consider rewriting your code to a reusable component, something like

```
function DayMeals(id, title) {
  var self = this;

  this.id = id;

  this.$el = document.createElement('div');
  this.$el.classList.add('row');
  this.$el.innerHTML = '<h4>' + title + '</h4><input type="text"/><button>Add</button><ol></ol>';

  this.$list = this.$el.querySelector('ol');
  this.$input = this.$el.querySelector('input');
  this.$addButton = this.$el.querySelector('button');

  this.meals = this.getFromStorage();
  this.updateView();

  this.$addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.add(self.$input.value);
  });

  this.$el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.dataset.remove) {
      self.remove(e.target.dataset.remove)
    }
  });
}

DayMeals.prototype.getFromStorage = function() {
  var storage = localStorage.getItem(this.id);
  return storage ? JSON.parse(storage) : [];
};

DayMeals.prototype.putToStorage = function() {
  localStorage.setItem(this.id, JSON.stringify(this.meals));
};

DayMeals.prototype.add = function(meal) {
  this.meals.push(meal);
  this.putToStorage();
  this.updateView();
};

DayMeals.prototype.remove = function(index) {
  this.meals.splice(index, 1);
  this.putToStorage();
  this.updateView();
};

DayMeals.prototype.updateView = function() {
  var listContent = '';

  this.meals.forEach(function(meal, i) {
    listContent += '<li>' + meal + '<button data-remove="' + i + '">x</button></li>';
  });

  this.$list.innerHTML = listContent;
};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4s0yb3g/1/)

Comment: Woah, thanks Dennis! I couldn't see any HTML in your fiddle, was that changed at all? I can see from the bottom half where it's getting the list from storage, the add, remove and show functions, but can't see where that references back to the HTML. Thanks!

Comment: `DayMeals` instance has `$el` property - a DOM node. All you need to do is append it where you need it. Check the very bottom of js code in the fiddle.

Comment: Ah right, I wasn't familiar with this approach, way more elegant than what I was using. So adding further weekday variables plus corresponding $el properties will allow each day to use the functions without duplication? Additionally, would I be able to use CSS to manipulate this into 2 columns with ingredients on the right? (As in the original fiddle)

Comment: Yes. There are monday and tuesday widgets in the fiddle and they are totally independent. Just create more `DayMeals` instances with needed configuration and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a huge help! Sorry last Q, any idea how I can have one of the DayMeals instance  in a second column? As appendChild seems to make it part of the same list, would something like a new function ColumnTwo() work using similar code to the above?

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions named 'add', and last one is overriding first one. Name them properly, i.e. **mondayAdd**, **tuesdayAdd**. Same thing goes for other functions that share the same name: 'show', 'remove'.

Comment: Thanks! I've amended the function names to something unique but now the list in storage does not show and buttons don't work. Am I missing something else? https://jsfiddle.net/sarwech/vrn5s2ns/8/

Comment: You are still binding old function (not existent) for button click event. `document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', add);` should be `document.getElementById('add1').addEventListener('click', mondayAdd);`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated these now and got Tuesday working but for Monday I'm getting an error. "mondaylist.push is not a defined function" this is strange as the code for mondayAdd looks fine? https://jsfiddle.net/sarwech/vrn5s2ns/9/ EDIT: right so this works on android chrome but not windows Chrome! Progress though. Thanks a lot!